# Downgraded GNU make not working

Tags: make, gnu

Since downgrading GNU make from 4.1 to 3.81, make isn't working. This is the method used for the downgrade:

- In `/usr/bin` renamed `make` to `make-4.1`
- Downloaded make 3.81 from gnu.org
- Extracted `make-3.81.tar.bz2` into `/usr/bin`
- Renamed `make-3.81` to `make`.

Now when I run make it's like it doesn't exist. How to get GNU make 3.81 working?

Comment: Where's the compiling step?

Comment: You mean I need to I need to compile from source?

Comment: I think, your question is "How do I install an older version of make on my <DISTRO-NAME>, and pin it". That will yield better results. You will probably get an answer using your distributions package manager, which is the *much* *cleaner* approach to software installation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I started a new thread at  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294121/how-do-i-install-an-older-version-of-gnu-make-using-apt.

Comment: This link is specific to debian, but much of it is relevant to other distros too: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, breaking vendor space (here, the `/usr/bin` directory) is rather a bad idea, as other vendor packages may depend on `make` 4.1 being available, or vendor updates to `make` may conflict or break on account of the manual changes made to the vendor space, or perhaps undo your changes. A better option is to install your version of `make` elsewhere, for example to `/usr/local/bin`—though on *BSD systems that area is used by packages, so check your vendor's documentation on where things should go, then pick somewhere else when making a software depot of your own, e.g. `/opt` or whatever made-up name is suitable to your environment. Granted, this does mean that you are responsible for updates (in particular, security updates) to the software under that software depot, a drawback that can vary from negligible to horrific, depending on the software and site.

As to the compile step, it would run (with a custom software depot path of `/usr/local`) along the lines of:

```
tar xjf make-3.81.tar.bz2
cd make-3.81
./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install
```

Any application that then needs the olden version of `make` would need to set the `PATH` environment variable to list `/usr/local/bin` before the `/usr/bin` (or now on some Linux, also `/bin`) directories.

```
env PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH yoursoftwarethatneedsmake3.81 ...
```

Or manually in the shell rc or webserver or whatnot configuration. This could be problematical should an application need the old version of `make`, but does need something else from `/usr/bin` that is masked by other software under `/usr/local/bin`; to avoid this, `make` could be installed to a versioned directory:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/`uname -m`/make-3.81
```

And then applications would need (assuming amd64 on Linux) `/opt/x86_64/make-3.81/bin` listed first in their `PATH`. Or, if you only run one architecture you could simplify the path to just `/opt/make-3.81`, or go more complicated with `/opt/centos7/x86_64/make-3.81` to support multiple operating systems under a single tree. As additional software is installed in such a fashion, something like [Stow](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Stow) may help managing such versioned installs without making `PATH` tediously long. With sufficient care, attention, and resources, a software depot built something along these lines may evolve into something like [Apollo](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2014/11/apollo-amazon-deployment-engine.html), though the ideal software depot form (if any!) for a particular site will vary depending on the size of the site, how much out-of-vendor-control software needs to be installed, etc.